# What is the pattern name when functions implementing interfaces?

Tags: go

In Go we can create functions that implement an interface, like `http.Handler` interface and concrete type `http.HandlerFunc`. I created another simple example of this kind of pattern to calculate bonus for different employees.

```golang
type BonusCalculator interface {
    Calculate(salary float64) float64
}

type BonusFunc func(salary float64) float64

func (bonus BonusFunc) Calculate(salary float64) float64 {
    return bonus(salary)
}

var (
    DeveloperBonus BonusFunc = func(salary float64) float64 { return salary*1.5 + 2500.00 }
    ManagerBonus   BonusFunc = func(salary float64) float64 { return salary * 2.0 }
    DirectorBonus  BonusFunc = func(salary float64) float64 { return salary * 3.3 }
)

func CalculateBonus (bonus BonusCalculator, salary float64) float64 {
  return bonus.Calculate(salary)
}

func main() {
    bonus := CalculateBonus(DirectorBonus, 35000.00)
    fmt.Printf("bonus %.2f", bonus)
}
```

So above we have simple `BonusFuncs` implementing interface `BonusCalculator` instead of use structs to do the same.

Is there a name to this pattern? I see it in many places and never found a name for it.

Comment: The term _adapter_ is mentioned in [the documentation of the `HandlerFunc` type](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandlerFunc).

Comment: I see the point in calling `http.HandlerFunc` an adapter as it structurally adapts the interface of the function by adding the `ServeHTTP()` method. For the example above, it's also worth looking at the *strategy pattern* as you encapsulate different behaviors in different interchangeable values satisfying the same interface. See how the strategy pattern relates to the adapter pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46023431/2102916.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a name to this pattern? I see it in many places and never found a name for it.

Yes, this pattern is called [**Adapter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) because it allows some sort of "interface" (closures in this case) to be used as another kind of interface (a type that satisfies `BonusCalculator`).

In your example, you have an interface `BonusCalculator`:

```
type BonusCalculator interface {
    Calculate(salary float64) float64
}
```

However, you have closures of type `func(salary float64) float64`, and you want to be able to pass them when a type that satisfies `BonusFunc` is required, i.e., a type that has the method `Calculate(salary float64) float64` (the closures don't have a method with such name, so they don't satisfy `BonusCalculator`).

What you want is to *adapt* a `func(salary float64) float64` to a `BonusCalculator`. So, you define a new type, `BonusFunc`, which is the *adapter*. It will derive from the closure type you want to adapt and, in turn, will satisfy `BonusCalculator` by defining a method `Calculate(salary float64) float64` on it that simply calls the underlying closure:

```
type BonusFunc func(salary float64) float64

func (bonus BonusFunc) Calculate(salary float64) float64 {
    return bonus(salary)
}
```

The `BonusFunc` is the *Adapter*; it exists only for adapting a `func(salary float64) float64` so that the interface `BonusCalculator` can be satisfied. Now, whenever you assign a `func(salary float64) float64` to a `BonusFunc`, you obtain a value that satisfies `Bonuscalculator`.